# htaccess redirect url if matching exact string length?

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a lot of old urls inbound pointing to incorrect locations, trying to forward to new location.  These are going to the root directory so I can't just forward everything.

One way to get a good chunk of them on to the new place is finding ones with a session ID in the query string.  It always has 32 characters, preceded by s=

```
https://www.example.com/some-url-name-1233/?s=ba4a8a734b666b8d43499e5d497599a6
```

Need to move that to (and drop the session ID)

```
https://www.example.com/newfolder/some-url-name-1233/
```

I can't get the `.htaccess` redirect to match that string.

I've tried multiple ways, most recent being:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)s=([^.]{32})$ https://www.example.com/newfolder/$1 [L,R=301]
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: "These are going to the root directory so I can't just forward everything." - What do you mean exactly? That doesn't sound like a reason as to why you "can't just forward everything". (?)

Comment: Reason everything in root can't be forwarded to the new location is because there is new content in the root folder and it doesn't need to be forwarded to the /newfolder/ location.  But everything with a session ID s=xyz does.

Answer (score 1):

This is an often answere, fully documented issue: you cannot access a request's query string by means of a `RewriteRule`. You need to use a `RewriteCond` for that:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^s=[^&]{32}(&|$)
RewriteRule ^ https://www.example.com/newfolder%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=301,QSD]
```

I also fixed some other details.

Comment: This doesn't "drop the session ID". And the regex `[^.]{32}` does not really make sense in this context. It should at least be `[^&]{32}` to match a single URL parameter value, or be more specific and match a hex value (which is what the session ID looks like).

Comment: @MrWhite Thanks, I indeed forgot about the mentioning of the dropping of the session id. Though I am not really convinced that an answer leading the OP into the right direction necessarily needs to solve every facet of a task.

Comment: @MrWhite About the regular expression ... Since the OP did not mention what kind of session id those are I hesitate to simply _assume_ a specific type. Which also means that I cannot assume a specific character set those ids might be build upon. Yes, possibly there could be additional query args from a technical point of view. But again the OP says nothing about that ... Again: I doubt that an answer should only be of value of all possible options that are theoretically left open by a vague question are answered exhaustively.

Comment: Unfortunately this did not work.  I will research further using RewriteCond methods as well.  Not trying to be vague, so if additional information is needed LMK.

Comment: The first information you'd need to supply is to say what "did not work" actually means ... No redirection occurs? The wrong redirection? Some internal error on the server? What does your browser's network console say what it receives back for the request? Did you really make sure you are not looking at a cached result?

Comment: "`[&|S]`" should be `(&|S)`. @alex2k5